# Where can I find pthreads for Linux?

Tags: linux, pthreads, sphinx

I do not have pthreads in my system.

Linux vps-sohoportal.hspheredns.com 2.6.18-294.26.1.el5.lve0.8.18xen #1 SMP Thu Feb 24 12:15:18 EET 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

When I try to configure sphinx have error:

configuring Sphinx

---

```
checking for CFLAGS needed for pthreads...
checking for LIBS needed for pthreads...
checking for pthreads... configure: error: no working pthreads library found
```

Comment: what kind of linux is this? `lsb_release -a`

Comment: LSB Version:    :core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-ia32:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-ia32:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-ia32:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: CloudLinuxServer
Description:    CloudLinux Server release 5.6
Release:        5.6
Codename:       n/a

Comment: same as.. as I think. Yum and RPM are managers of packeges

Comment: Are you configuring for a cross-compile or native-compile?

Comment: Pardon? I don't understand your question. I downloaded sphinx from official website and do like as in instruction. First of all extract here then try use ./configure and have this error message

Comment: Check the log (`configure.log` or something), it contains the actual program failing to compile during the check (search for "pthreads"). You should be able to move from there.

Comment: Are you mean remove checks for pthreads? I can do it. but Why?

Comment: Nooo. I mean look to the log and se what failed (**and why**). BTW, I suspect you DO have package libc-dev, glibc-dev, libc6-dev or something like that installed, or not?

Comment: glibc-devel-2.5-65.x86_64 already installed and latest version

Comment: I find next:: configure:6403: gcc -o conftest -Wall -g -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -O3 -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include  conftest.c -ldl -lm -lz -lexpat  -L/usr/local/lib -lrt  >&5
conftest.c: In function 'main':
conftest.c:92: warning: unused variable 'once_init'
configure:6403: $? = 0
configure:6403: ./conftest
./conftest: error while loading shared libraries: libexpat.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
configure:6403: $? = 127

Comment: Is this mean problem in libexpat.so.1 ?

Comment: Yes. It's strange, since expat is a XML parser, but I suspect you do not have it installed. Try installing it with its devel package.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3448/discussion-between-jpalecek-and-user900898)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the `pthread-stubs` package of your distribution. Check in your package manager.

If you can't find it, it should be shipped with your compiler.

Comment: I have not this package in list of avaliable package. Get list by command yum list > list_packages . Then open this file in vim and try search - but 'Pattern not found'

Comment: yum install libxcb-devel
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, rhnplugin
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * cloudlinux-base: repo.cloudlinux.com
 * cloudlinux-updates: repo.cloudlinux.com
 * cloudlinux-x86_64-server-5: slc-proxy.cl-mirror.net
 * rpmforge: apt.sw.be
Excluding Packages in global exclude list
Finished
Setting up Install Process
No package libxcb-devel available.
Nothing to do
((((

Comment: Wormsparty's answer looks good, for Fedora 20 I find that libxcb-devel package, install it with yum, and find that it delivers /usr/lib64/pkgconfig/pthread-stubs.pc

Answer (score 0):

For ubuntu/apt users, here is how we find and install the package:

```bash
$ apt search pthread-stubs
Sorting... Done. Full Text Search... Done
libpthread-stubs0-dev/kinetic 0.4-1build2 amd64
  pthread stubs not provided by native libc, development files

$ sudo apt install libpthread-stubs0-dev
```

(Thanks to the accepted answer in this thread.)

Also, in ubuntu 22, it is installed under `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` dir.